# Unexpected header information from fgets

Tags: c, header, line, fgets

This is a really simple problem so I know I'm missing something obvious, but I can't seem to figure it out. I am simply trying to read text line by line using fgets, however I am getting additional information that I am assuming is associated with the file header.

Long story short, I made a new text file using nano that is simply one decimal digit per line, i.e.:

```
2
8
3
4
...
```

My code to read the file is:

```
char line[20];
FILE * fp;
fp = fopen(infile, "r");
if (fp == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
    ... do some stuff ...
}
fclose(fp);
```

However, the first line it returns is `"\177ELF\002\001\001"`, and all subsequent lines until it terminates are empty `""`.

Any suggestions as to why I'm not reading what I expect? Did creating the file with nano introduce extra heading junk that I don't want? If so, how might I avoid this?

Comment: What is `infile`? Looks as if `infile` contains a path to some ELF file.

Comment: I don't see any output function. Where is the [mcve]?

Comment: You should probably just delete this question. It is unlikely to help anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Wow I'm a dumbass... I was wondering what an ELF tag was doing on a txt file, but I was too careless to check the script that implemented the function itself with the filename. Switched naming conventions and forgot to update that file.

Answer (score -1):

You're reading the wrong file here. Executables, also known as ELF files on many systems, start with "\177ELF\002\001\001". It's therefore safe to say that infile has an incorrect value.